# 【Rails】Login during testing in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

#### Assumptions

We are developing with Ruby on Rails and creating test code with Rspec.

###### Environment

```
Ruby 2.6.5
Rails 6.0.3
RSpec 3.11
devise 4.7.1
```

#### What I would like to achieve.

In Rspec, I am expecting a 200 code, but it returns a 401 code.
I modified the code below to log in, but it still fails to log in and returns a 401 code.
How can I modify it so that it logs in and returns a 200 code?

#### Problem/error message you are encountering

###### Rspec logs

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.status).to eq 200
expected: 200
     got: 401
```

#### Source code in question

infos_controller_spec.rb

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

module Api::V1::Admin
  RSpec.describe InfosController, type: :controller do
    describe "GET /form_init" do
      let!(:user){create :user}
      it "should 200" do
        login_user(user)
        get :form_init
        expect(response.status).to eq 200
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
require "devise"
Dir[File.expand_path("./spec/support/*.rb")].each{|f| require f}
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.expect_with :rspec do |c|
    c.syntax = :expect
  end
  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
  config.include ControllerMacros, type: :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
end
```

spec/support/controller_macros.rb

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user(user)
    @request.env['devise.mapping'] = Devise.mappings[:user]

    sign_in(user, scope: :user)
  end
end
```

Comment: failing tests is a normal part of Rails development. Why does my test fail? You need to do the usual debugging methods, inserting `puts` or `debugger` statements to investigate the cause. It's what we do most of the time in Rails development!

Comment: Remember, when you make a `get` request, you're calling a process on a server that lives outside the scope of your RSpec test. That request needs to tell the server that the user is logged in somehow. This is usually accomplished with cookies/sessions or headers. I see you logging in the user in your test. But, I don't see anything here that says you're creating a session on the server and sending a cookie with the session id from the client (which in this case is the RSpec test) to the server.